# How do i get MS EXCEL to Connect to MYSQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

How Can i get Microsoft Excel 2010 to Connect to MYSQL Server (5.6.12)

I installed MYSQL as a WAMP installation

Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit

MYSQL  5.6.12

Apache 2.4.4

PHP    5.4.16

this should be straight forward, but i've obviously missed something

Now.. When i open Excel 2010

i then go to "Data"

i then go to "From Other Sources"

i then select "From SQL Server"

I'm then presented with the Data Connection Wizard

I have the Log on Credentials (that's not an issue)

I'm Logging on with "Use the following User Name and Password"

i require the SERVER NAME

but i keep getting this error

[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied

I understand the concept of what needs to happen, that being, i need to specify the connection path of MYSQL to Excel

Now..   so far i have done this...

1. Ensured that the WAMP Server was ONLINE and the Service was STARTED
2. obviously the default server is     `localhost`    that does not work, but then again on my machine that only brings up the WAMP page  (so that's Understandable)
3. i usually access MYSQL via PhpMyAdmin  the URL for the Login page is

http://`localhost`/phpmyadmin/

i tried entering that (that doesn't work either, but then again, i understand that is only the front end)

so..

1. i tried typing in   MYSQL  ,   mysql   ,  MYSQL5.6.12   , mysql/mysql5.6.12

none of that worked

1. the MYSQL install path is

C:\WAMP\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12

so.. Logically if i gave that to Excel, it should find it,  But it didn't

1. I researched the Net and everything Either says Use the Wizard , but doesn't go into detail on the Server Name,  one place said to install Microsoft Connector, I have done so.. it didnt' help
2. I have tried the Server Name as    `localhost` ,     http://`localhost` , 127.0.0.1    didn't work
3. Using MYSQL CLI i entered    "status;"  and used the connection name     `localhost` via TCP/IP     didn't work
4. i went into MYSQL buddy  and i found this

You are connected to MySQL 5.6.12 with the user     Martin.Kuliza@`localhost`.

i tried this also, didn't work

1. i noticed the URL on the command line title as being

C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe - C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12.bin\mysql.exe -u

i entered all this... didn't work

i entered the part Starting from C:\wamp.... Didn't work

1. I've tried entering   wamp, WAMP,  Apache,  APACHE,  apache

I've tried dozens of combinations

I've tried finding the config file for connector in case that had something to do with it (couldn't find it)

i've tried looking at the config.inc.php file for clues,

I'm stuck and need some help  (for this seemingly simple problem)

it's just a Connection Wizard and i'm honestly gobsmacked that i actually need to ask the forum for help, but, Sadly i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FOUND A SOLUTION...

Kudos to HongTAT for keeping me on the right path....

(Even though i did do all the initial stuff that you posted, before i actually posted the question, The Act of you Posting it, Got me Looking at it a little deeper...

One thing led to another and i found the solution...  Thank you

i suspect some sort of incompatibility issue must have been at fault here
i noticed that Power Query 64 bit would not install on my 64bit system

instead Power Query installer provided an Error that simply stated to the effect of:

since office is 32bit you can't install 64bit Power Query

but, i did install Connector/ODBC and Connector/Net as 64bit

perhaps there was something in that configuration that didn't mesh well with each other.

Also,  Aparently "bit-ness"  is a confusing term that is supposed to mean ( Ensure that that bit instruction set of the of the ODBC Connector Matches the bit instruction set of Power Query in Excel)

In actual fact you don't need Power Query or Visual Studio for that matter

However i can see the benefit of power Query, at this stage

WHAT I DID...

I uninstalled all traces of Microsoft Visual Studio from Add/Remove Programs

I Uninstalled all Traces of Visual C++ Redistributable from Add/Remove Programs

I Uninstalled Power Query from Add/Remove Programs

I Uninstalled MYSQL Connector/ODBC from Add/Remove Programs

I Uninstalled MYSQL Connector/Net from Add/Remove Programs

i left the WAMP Installation and MYSQL Intact

i conducted a Windows Update

i restarted the system

i then downloaded the following and installed it

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=450946

Now.. Even though this Package installation is the same thing as installing it 1 by 1

i found that by doing a "CUSTOM INSTALLATION"

and installing all products EXCEPT FOR MYSQL SERVER

i was able to connect via the connector/net to the MYSQL Database right away

LASTLY  i installed Power Query for Excel (since that was the whole point to begin with)

and this time it connected right away and Worked Perfectly

the Server Name was    `localhost`

as i suspected

and the credentials were correct as i suspected

the only thing was that i had to set it up without Encryption of password

i got a message saying something like   My Version of Office did not support encryption
or something to that effect

but, i connected without encryption and it worked perfectly

PROBLEM SOLVED

I NOW DEEM THIS QUESTION TO BE RESOLVED

THANKYOU TO HongTat

Answer (score 1):

Have you done this?

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/connect-to-a-mysql-database-HA104019820.aspx

> Before you can connect to a MySQL database, you need the MySQL
>   Connector on your computer. To install the MySQL Connector
>   (Connector/Net), go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=278885
>   and download Connector/Net 6.6.5 for Microsoft Windows. The driver
>   bit-ness needs to match the Microsoft Power Query for Excel add-in
>   installation (32-bit or 64-bit).

Comment: I have done that,  I have downloaded Connector/Net 6.6.5 and installed it, the part that throws me a bit is .. "What is Bit-ness"  I Understand that it's a driver, and i  have recently learned that i need to go to Administrative service Under ODBC Data Source Administrator,  and Under Drivers,  i can see {SQL SERVER Version 6.01.7601.17514}  i understand that i want to create a System DSN, None are Listed , so i ADD a new one,   A driver does show up on the next screen (i assume this is normal) i click Finish. and it attempts to log in as per what Excel tried to do. i get asked 3 questions

Comment: Question 1. What name do you want to refer to the database as,   I answer - MYSQL    Question 2. How do you want to describe the database source,   My Answer   MYSQL    Question 3  Which SQL Server do you want to connect to   (Now.. this has an arrow, which suggests a dropdown list, but.. There is nothing in the list,  so i enter   localhost   i get the same error

Comment: I HAVE MADE SOME PROGRESS, i discovered that i did not have Microsoft Power Query for Excel Add in installed,  i didn't even know what it was,  anyway.. i have it now,   but regardless of whether im using Power Query or ODBC Connector, i find they all do the same thing essentially,  i still get the same error,  it appears that it wont recognise the server name,    my server name is  btoserver it's not on a domain   i imagine that i would use either btoserver   or   <code>localhost</code> i think this is the root of the problem,  PS there is still nothing in the dropdown list next to (Server:)

Comment: I FINALLY FOUND AN ANSWER, However since i'm a new user, i can't post Until Midday today, (5 hours left), LOL   Standy at that time for the answer,  Thankyou Hong Tat for you help, i will clarify this in my answer,  take care

Answer (score -5):

Did you try googling this before you posted your question? Because if you spent at least 10 seconds searching the internet, you would have found the answer to your question.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/connect-to-a-mysql-database-HA104019820.aspx

Comment: yes, thanks for that,i did mention "i searched the net" i actually did find that in about 15seconds or so.  and i found this as well http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tUiaK5fRH7k  and i'm still having the same problem,  I understand your comment, and i know what a P.I.T.A it is to answer questions on STACK from people who don't bother to research,  I'M NOT ONE OF THOSE.. OK   I've clearly researched this for close to an hour and am continuing to do so.  and i still have a problem.  it's still the same error,   I'm not a newbie or a time waster,   Any other ideas (without the sarcasm)